# Broadband cable to wireless

Tags: internet

Is there any software out there which can use the cable broadband, which is going into my computer and make it go out wireless with my wifi, so I can use laptops throughout the house?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[2hotspot](http://download.cnet.com/2hotspot/3000-2654_4-10495884.html) seems to do what you ask:

From 2hotspot  :

> A powerful software that enables the
>   instant creation wireless hotspots
>   using your wireless router or WIFI
>   card. With this free software you can,
>   run your own free or commercial
>   wireless hotspot network; Create local
>   wireless communities where bulletin
>   board, chat, and forums available
>   locally with or without Internet
>   service; Share your broadband service,
>   split your ISP bill, control shared
>   bandwidth; Used by individuals &
>   corporations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows then [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/bfd3bd31-82f0-4b9c-9cde-fb92bc2b14771033.mspx) will do this.  ([Older XP Article on ICS.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126))

Answer (score 1):

Windows has Internet Connection Sharing built in, and Mac OS X has a similar facility.  Just google it, no additional software required.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can just add a USB Wifi stick to your PC and share your internet connection.  The laptops will be able to pick up the Wifi from the PC and route through that.

Add the stick, then right click on your wired network connection to share it.